# SqlConnection.Open fails but works in SSMS

Tags: c#, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have a problem establishing a Database connection from C# code. I recreated the code as a minimal example in PowerShell:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectrionString = "data source=MyServer\MyDb,1234;initial catalog=MyDb;user id=someone;pwd=Password;"
$conn.Open();
```

If I open the connection via SSMS with the same Server name, SQL Server Authentication and the same credentials, it works. Locally on the server and also remotely.

However the above code throws an error:

```
"Cannot open database "MyDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'someone'."
In line:1
+ $conn.Open();
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

Connecting as `sa` works from script, also I can connect to other servers running cloned instances of the database just fine. Connecting to the server with the given credentials and options via Visual Studio 2022 also fails.

Mixed login mode is set.

Since the databases are cloned, but not the server installations, I guess, that there is some kind of setting in MSSQL 2016, that prevents login as `someone` from other sources than SSMS, but allows it for sa. But I just don't know of any such setting.

Comment: Does `someone` actually have access to `MyDb`? When you make a connection in SMSS you will by default connect to `master`, unless your explicitly override it. As you mention cloning, I suspect you may have a disconnect between logins and database users. `sa`, of course, can always access any database.

Comment: As an aside, specifying an instance as `server\instance,port` is a bad idea because `instance` is ignored in this case -- the `port` will be leading. *Either* specify the instance name, and ensure port 1434 is available to do instance name resolution, *or* specify the port explicitly, but then you should probably leave out the instance name, as it's potentially confusing or even misleading (a completely different instance might be listening on that port). The only reason including the instance might be desirable there is to clue in ignorant readers -- but instance lookup is a better idea.

Comment: You are right, ```someone``` didn't actually have the rights to connect to ```MyDb```. I set that flag in the Security settings and now it is working like a charm